# BigDL : Saving a model throws Exception: "This is a deprecated method. Please use saveModel instead."

Tags: bigdl, analytics-zoo

I am using BigDL + Analytics-Zoo for doing Anomaly detection on time-series data.
When I try to save the model using the .save() method after training,
I am getting the Exception: "This is a deprecated method. Please use saveModel instead."

Generally, deprecations come as a warning, but here it is thrown as an Exception, so I am wondering is this real reason for the Exception? or is there some other reason behind this?
If I call '`saveModel`' method, it works, but my question is why should the API still keeping a `.save()` method if it is not supported?

```
model.save(model_path, over_write=True)
```

.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-b922e545922f> in <module>()
----> 1 model.save(model_path, over_write=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zoo/pipeline/api/keras/engine/topology.py in save(self, path, over_write)
     31 class KerasNet(ZooKerasLayer):
     32     def save(self, path, over_write=False):
---> 33         raise Exception("This is a deprecated method. Please use saveModel instead.")
     34 
     35     def saveModel(self, modelPath, weightPath=None, over_write=False):

Exception: This is a deprecated method. Please use saveModel instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

it is legacy issue, please use saveModel instead.